# SQL Server dropping global temp tables very slow

Tags: sql-server

Running SQL Server 2016

I'm having an issue where dropping tables in tempdb takes 20 to 30 seconds. Otherwise, all databases (including tempdb) seem to be performing normally. SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE all perform as expected. I've ensured there are no open transactions on the tables. Even the below example hangs:

```
CREATE TABLE ##delme (foo INT)
DROP TABLE ##delme
```

Even when closing the session and all transactions that created a global temp table, the implicit dropping of that table takes the same amount of time (20-30 seconds). The only solution I have so far is to restart the SQL Server service, which is far from ideal in a production environment and the issue eventually comes back anyway.

Is there any way to trace or diagnose what could be causing this type of slowness?

EDIT: Added Session wait stats:

[Session wait stats from sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBxHD.png)

Comment: Try CREATE TABLE #delme (foo INT)  , and create temp tables like this without ## . Avoid using ## to create tables it slow down i every sql server.

Comment: @Adamszsz same issue with local temp tables as well

Comment: What are the Session Wait Stats for a session that just creates and drops a temp table? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Get [whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/) and run it from another session to see what it's waiting on or blocked by

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I edited the original post to include session wait stats

Comment: So no significant waits, what about SET STATISTICS TIME ON?  Do you see high CPU use?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This is the output from a DROP TABLE statement with SET STATISTICS TIME ON. CPU time is quite high.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16078 ms,  elapsed time = 16362 ms.

Comment: Are you using the latest Service Pack and CU for SQL 2016?

Comment: No, currently running Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4505219) - 13.0.4259.0 (X64)

Comment: SP1's been out-of-support for a couple of years now, so you should probably test on later version next.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks, I'll reach out to the appropriate folks on our team to try to get it upgraded to a version that's not EOL